# Is the MVC Controller Layer the ideal place for error handling?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

It would seem so to me, because nearly all exceptions thrown downstream of whatever routes requests to controllers, will be thrown in a controller or something downstream from a controller.  There is nothing upstream from a controller except a view, which is simply a presentation of what happened in the controller.

Comment: but what if there is some error in a view?

Comment: @ajay - then your doing it wrong.  You shouldn't encounter a HTTP 500 on something that is only 'displaying' data.  All logic, data connections, model binding, etc. should happen in the controller/model and not in the view.

Comment: @Tommy Not really, of course the view is only displaying data but to do that it has access to a model, usually this is more than just a simple data-container so it can cause exceptions to be thrown. So don't assume rendering your view won't throw exceptions.

Comment: @Mendelt, we are using strongly typed views, so if there are any issues between view and model, we really should be sorting them out during development and testing.

Comment: I wasn't talking about issues between view and model. I was talking about issues inside the model. If your model is more than a simple data-container it can throw exceptions when the view reads a property or calls a method.
An example I've seen a couple of times were exceptions thrown by Linq to SQL when lazy loading objects. Say you have a ShoppingCart class that has items, enumerating the items to display them is typical view-logic. But this can cause the model to do a database call, this can break, and this will break while rendering the view outside of the action method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller actions are an ideal place for most of the error handling but not all of it.

The view isn't rendered until after your controller action finishes executing. So  if for example you pass the view a viewmodel that is more than a simple data container and it throws an exception while the view is being rendered (not an uncommon scenario). You can't catch this in your controller action.

Here's a tool you can use to catch exceptions outside the controller
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's usually determined by the Controller which View you need to display so errors which occur at lower levels e.g. BLL/DAL, can still do error handling and can just be aided by the controller e.g.

```
public ActionResult DisplayObject(int id)
{
    // high level error handling
    using (MyRepo repo = new MyRepo()) 
    {
        var obj = repo.GetObj(id);
        if (obj == null)
            return View("ErrorDisplayingObject");
        else
            return View("ObjectDetails");
    }
}
...

public ActionResult SaveObject(int id, string param1, string param2)
{
    // high level error handling
    using (MyRepo repo = new MyRepo()) 
    {
        var obj = repo.GetObj(id);
        if (obj != null)
        {
            obj1.Param1 = param1;
            obj2.Param2 = param2;
            if (repo.Save())
                return View("SaveConfirmation");
        }          
    }
    return View("ErrorSavingObject");
}

...
public class MyRepo
{
    public MyObject GetObj(int id)
    {
        // low level error handling
        try
        {
            // retrieve object

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
             return null;
        }
    }

    public bool Save()
    {
        // low level error handling
        try
        {
            // save data
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree totally about that sort of lower level error handling, just not the way you're doing it.  Why return false if something doesn't save?  Why not just let the exception bubble up?

Comment: @ProfK: You can indeed let it bubble up, the above is just an example of the many ways you can do it :) Personally...I would always let the exception bubble up as you would want to know *exactly* why it never saved, even output this in the view itself.

Answer (score 1):

Model has to be the most appropriate place where u can do the validation. Ideally model has to be the place where *domain model* should be place.. So, that makes it an ideal place to do error validation

Comment: Cheers for the model. Controllers should be lean and mean. And models should be fat. I actually break my validation and data access into a service and repository layer. But - here's a good start on model validation, http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the exception and what your action does. For example, if you´re saving an entity that could possibly be breaking
some business rules, then it is expected that your BLL throws an exception (e.g. BusinessRuleXXException) to signal this
non-compliance situation. In this case, you have to handle that exception (the Controller is a good place for doing this) and show the user an appropriate message indicating
what is wrong (You can not save this because of bla bla...).

On the other hand, you may have a buggy application in wich
you´re performing some action and you provoke an error, like for example a PK constraint being violated or maybe an external 
service is unavailable or any other situations that are not expected an represent real exceptions in your application. For this kind 
of errors, my suggestion is to handle them globally by using either a HandleError filter or a custom filter that handles errors
and logs them, and redirect the user to an error page where a friendly "Sorry, something went wrong. A team of highly trained monkeys has been dispatched to deal with this situation" message is shown.

Regards.